# LaTeX: How to add a a label to a VerbatimInput from Fancyvrb

Tags: latex

I want to include a data file in my paper. I would like to import it verbatim. I'm already using `fancyvrb` to use verbatim in footnotes, that is why I'm trying to use that package; `fancyverb` is not a requirement. However, just adding `"label=data:label"` doesn't seem to work. I have looked through the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf) for `fancyvrb`, but that did not answer my question. Is there a way to include a file verbatim and be able to reference to it?

I'm using TexStudio 2.6.6 on Windows 8.1.

My minimum working example is here:

**file.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
A file and its content:
\VerbatimInput[label=data:label]{data.dat}
This should be a number: \ref{data:label}.\\
End of file.
\end{document}
```

**data.dat**

```
some data
on several lines.
```

**Output**

```
A file and its content:
some data
on several lines.
This should be a number: ??.
End of file.
```

**Output from Build:**

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "file".tex

Process exited normally
```

**Output from Log/Issues:**

```
line 7: Reference `data:label' on page 1 undefined
There were undefined references.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it myself;

Using the `listings` package, it was just a matter of using `\lstset{language={}}` and then including the text using `\lstinputlisting` with the correct options.

-The text is not a typical monospaced font, but it is close enough.-

By changing `\lstset` to `\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,language={}}` the font is monospaced.

New **file.tex**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
A file and its content:
%\lstset{language={}} % changed
\lstset{basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,language={}}
\lstinputlisting[caption=data.dat,label=data:label]{data.dat}
This is now a number: \ref{data:label}.\\
End of file.
\end{document}
```

New **output**:

```
A file and its content:
Listing 1: data.dat
some data
on several lines .
This should be a number: 1.
End of file.
```